# Program to find specific pronouns

Tags: python

```
print("Noun Counter")
sentence = input("Write A sentence: ")
pronoun = (input("Choose a pronoun from Demonstrative, interrogative and indefinite: "))

if pronoun == "Demonstrative":
    source = sentence
    pronouns = ["this", "that", "these", "those"]  # download a list from somewhere
    print("Number of Demonstrative pronouns: ")
    count = 0
    words = source.split()
    for w in words:
        if w.lower() in pronouns:
            count += 1
    print(count)

elif pronoun == "Indefinite":
    source = sentence
    pronouns = ["Another", "anybody", "anyone", "anything", "each", "either", "enough", "everybody", "everyone",
                "everything", "little", "much", "neither", "nobody", "no one", "nothing", "one", "other", "somebody",
                "something", "Both", "few", "fewer", "many", "others", "several", "All", "any", "more", "most",
                "someone", "none", "some", "such"]  # download a list from somewhere
    print("Number of Indefinite pronouns: ")
    count = 0
    words = source.split()
    for w in words:
        if w.lower() in pronouns:
            count += 1
    print(count)

elif pronoun == "Interrogative":
    source = sentence
    pronouns = ["who", "whom", "whose", "what", "which"]
    print("Number of Interrogative pronouns: ")
    count = 0
    words = source.split()
    for w in words:
        if w.lower() in pronouns:
            count += 1
    print(count)

else:
    print("No pronoun found named: " + pronoun + ", please try again")
```

**This is code that can print the number of pronouns not the actual pronouns. It prints using the list. So is there any way i can get the pronouns to print. And please make it simple
**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a dictionary to get counts of every noun that you encounter(look out for comments saing "# addition" to see what has been changed in your code)-

```py
print("Noun Counter")
sentence = "This is code that can print the number of pronouns not the actual pronouns. " \
           "It prints using the list. So is there any way i can get the pronouns to print"
#input("Write A sentence: ")
pronoun = "Demonstrative"
#(input("Choose a pronoun from Demonstrative, interrogative and indefinite: "))


if pronoun == "Demonstrative":
    source = sentence
    pronouns = ["this", "that", "these", "those"]  # download a list from somewhere
    print("Number of Demonstrative pronouns: ")
    count = dict(zip(pronouns, [0]*len(pronouns)))  # addition
    words = source.split()
    for w in words:
        if w.lower() in pronouns:
            count[w.lower()] += 1  # addition
    print(count)

elif pronoun == "Indefinite":
    source = sentence
    pronouns = ["Another", "anybody", "anyone", "anything", "each", "either", "enough", "everybody", "everyone",
                "everything", "little", "much", "neither", "nobody", "no one", "nothing", "one", "other", "somebody",
                "something", "Both", "few", "fewer", "many", "others", "several", "All", "any", "more", "most",
                "someone", "none", "some", "such"]  # download a list from somewhere
    print("Number of Indefinite pronouns: ")
    count = dict(zip(pronouns, [0]*len(pronouns)))  # addition
    words = source.split()
    for w in words:
        if w.lower() in pronouns:
            count[w.lower()] += 1  # addition
    print(count)

elif pronoun == "Interrogative":
    source = sentence
    pronouns = ["who", "whom", "whose", "what", "which"]
    print("Number of Interrogative pronouns: ")
    count = dict(zip(pronouns, [0]*len(pronouns)))  # addition
    words = source.split()
    for w in words:
        if w.lower() in pronouns:
            count[w.lower()] += 1  # addition
    print(count)

else:
    print("No pronoun found named: " + pronoun + ", please try again")
```

#### Ouptut

```
Noun Counter
Number of Demonstrative pronouns: 
{'this': 1, 'that': 1, 'these': 0, 'those': 0}
```

Comment: Thanks @sai I was really looking for the help. This code is simple and covvenient. Thanks a lot

Comment: If it has addressed your your issue here, you should consider accepting the answer which will mark the question as answered